# Can't make an API request with React client

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongoose, connection, mern

I'm trying to make my react app reference a mongoDB database, but I'm having some serious issues with the request.

Here's the Service in the client.

```
import axios from "axios";

export default
{
    getAll: async () => {
        axios.get("api/quizlist").then((res) => {
            return res;
        }).catch(err =>
            {
                console.log(err);
            });
    }
}
```

Here's the Route I'm trying to call:

```
app.get("/api/quizlist", (req,res) => {
  console.log("Recieved Request");
  db.QuizData.find().then(data => {
    console.log("Passed Data");
    res.json(data);
  }).catch(err => {
    res.json(err);
  });
});
```

The error message I'm getting is

```
Error: Request failed with status code 504
    createError createError.js:16
    settle settle.js:17
    handleLoad xhr.js:61
```

I've tried to set up a proxy connection with this in the API:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "server": "nodemon server.js"
  }
```

and this in the client:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "proxy": "http://localhost:5000"
  }
```

(The API is connecting to port 5000)

Answer (score 0):

The `proxy` doesn't belong in the scripts object in the `package.json` file move it out like this

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:5000"
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
}
```

(you need to restart your app after making changes in the `package.json` file)

You are also missing a `/` in your front end request

Change

```
import axios from "axios";

export default
    {
        getAll: async () => {
            
            // change
            axios.get("api/quizlist").then((res) => {

            // to
            axios.get("/api/quizlist").then((res) => {

            return res;
        }).catch(err =>
        {
            console.log(err);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Still not working. It is possible there's code outside of what I've shown that might be the problem? Or even my overall project structure? I have a packagelock for the root folder, one for the API, and one for client. Could that be causing problems?

Comment: It might also be relevant that loggers in the service are sending to console, but ones in the route aren't.